# Securing apollo using meteor with no mongo

Tags: meteor, apollo-server

How to secure an apollo server that is being used by a meteor (with no mongo) client?

Currently the **meteor security relies heavily on mongo** to manage users, generate tokens, but due to price concerns and setting a mongo instance on a scalable server is a no go, mongo was dropped, now the question is how to replace it or make meteor security connect to a graphql server?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor user security relies on MongoDB, so if you don't use MongoDB, you can't get Meteor user security.

You can get general user security through manual checks in your resolvers. See the GitHunt example's user accounts system:

https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-API/blob/master/api/githubLogin.js

and it securely looks up the current logged-in user with eg

https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-API/blob/8dc58240ec00be227848f1054535ac47c6dc46b2/api/sql/schema.js#L85